# Windows Store App Unit test fails when using custom control

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store

I have a Windows Store App (C# + XAML) and wanted to create some unit tests for it.
I created the unit test project for this within my solution and the default test method works fine.
Then I added my project as reference to the unit test project and the tests stopped working:

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:00,8748072) ==========
------ Run test started ------
Updating the layout...

Copying files: Total 2 mb to layout...

Registering the application to run from layout...

Deployment complete. Full package name: "58d19822-a649-46ba-b3fd-36c60b2709d7_1.0.0.0_neutral__t4zwj4xd20b1w"

Failed to activate Windows Store app unit test executor. Error: The remote procedure call failed.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:05,0596667) ==========
```

I googled a lot and found a thread that explained the error could be within the App.xaml and indeed I could track it down to this TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" controls:HighLightString.FullText="{Binding Path=FullName}" controls:HighLightString.SelectedText="{Binding DataContext.QueryText, ElementName=resultsPanel}" controls:HighLightString.FgColor="{StaticResource SAPHighlightColor}"  Style="{StaticResource TileTitleTextStyle}" Margin="20,0,0,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

If I change it to:

```
<TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=FullName}" Style="{StaticResource TileTitleTextStyle}" Margin="20,0,0,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

the tests run fine but I do no longer have a search highlight on that text block.

How can I have both - the search highlights and running unit tests within my solution?

Comment: So, I actually ran into this same issue in my project. Do you by any chance have any other attached properties with the same property name? "FullText", it seems.

Comment: I solved the problem for my by removing the text block definition in the app.xaml and putting it into the search results page xaml definition. This way the app.xaml was "clean" and the unit tests can be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be related to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790477/winrt-mstest-runner-fails-when-using-ilist-t-properties-of-custom-types-from-xaml

As far as I can tell, use of some custom types in Xaml is incompatible with the WinRT unit test runner, because that does not provide proper [`IXamlType` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.ixamltype.aspx) implementations in some cases.

So it's possible that there's something about these attachable properties that you're using that causes the test runner to provider incorrect metadata for them. (Without being able to see your `HighLightString` class it's hard to be sure. But you can verify whether this is the case by turning on Mixed mode debugging for your unit test project, and debugging the tests. Configure Visual Studio to break on all CLR exceptions when Thrown (and not just when unhandled), and if you eventually hit a `NotImplementedException` (possibly after a few other exceptions) in a type called `RunTimeXamlSystemBaseType` then this is the problem you're running into.)

I've worked around this in the past by avoiding putting the relevant types in my `App.xaml`. You only run into this problem if you attempt to load the relevant Xaml. (Not much help if you actually need these things to be at global scope of course.)

Comment: i ran into this tonight because a style being shared across things references *something* that the test runner doesn't like.  i have it partially narrowed down but the workaround is a pain...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same Problem.
I use the HighlightOnErrors behaviour of the **Adventure Works Shopping Example** of
 **Microsft Prism for Windows 8.1** in a DataTemplate for a Listbox.

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:HighlightOnErrors PropertyErrors="{Binding Errors[Value], Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                         OriginalStyleName="VariationTableItemTextBoxStyle" 
                                                         HighlightStyleName="HighlightVariationTableItemTextBoxStyle"/>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The behavior works fine and the Unit Test run fine, but not with this behavior inside the Listbox Item emplate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug filed for this on Microsoft's Connect site here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/848688/unit-testing-windows-store-app-fails-when-style-contains-custom-attached-dependency-properties

The workaround listed is to reference the app's build .exe instead of using a project reference. I can confirm that that workaround does work.